# How to change the node js process name on windows 10?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a **node js** process running on windows 10. I want to change the name of the process so that i can get some performance details. I tried changing the **process.title** property of the **process** object but, it does not reflect in the power shell. I can find only **node** as the process name. Is there any other way to change the process name in windows.

Comment: On Windows, `process.title` affects the console title, but not the name of the process in the task manager. You can uniquely identify a process by its `process.pid`, however.

Answer (score 7):

In node.js, you can get/set `process.title`

In the browsers, you can get/set `document.title`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 5):

**Change name on OS level**
 1. Rename your node binary to `foobar`
 2. Change package.json start script from `node start.js` to `foobar start.js`

**Change name from JavaScript code**

You can't change process name from JavaScript code. Node.js is libuv + V8. JavaScript read and run after process already created.

Comment: If I rename **node binary** then I have to run all other node process as **foobar app.js** and all of them will have **foobar** as their process name. In my case i want the process name to be unique so that i can differentate them and find the respective **process id** to get the performance details. I am trying to get the process id without any means of communication with that process.

Comment: I added Change name from JavaScript code block.

Maybe, pid will help you?

Comment: This is my exact case. I have a couple of node js processes(they are not in parent-child relation) to run on windows. Among that i want one service to get the process id's of the other processes. By what means i can do this.

Comment: Can you press CTRL+T in the terminal, where the process run?

Comment: yes, i tried pressing **CTRL+T** but could not notice anything

Comment: Not the most elegant solution, but such is life in Windows-land. I made a copy of node.exe in its default install path and renamed it to nodexxx.exe. Nodexxx now works at the command line, and behaves exactly the same as node.exe.